# Where can I export AWS Cloudwatch Logs (for Loggly)?

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, loggly

I know they are storing them somewhere. Maybe a DynamoDB or S3 bucket?

I'd like to use Cloudwatch as a log archive for my EC2 instances, and set it up so that they are passed to Loggly for viewing/sorting/ etc.

I know Loggly recently released a way to grab logs from S3 buckets (https://www.loggly.com/docs/s3-logs/) but I can't seem to find the source of these logs on the AWS side.

My thoughts so far are:

- Maybe I could set up a Metric/Alarm to pass all incoming logs to Loggly?
- I could possibly gain access to where AWS stores these Cloudwatch Logs?
- Set up a cron somewhere that bounces Cloudwatch logs to an S3 bucket, and go from there?
- Use Cloudwatch API calls in a cron to directly grab logs and send them to Loggly through an HTTP post etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API will let you export data to S3, however note it's for historical data not real time... data up to a few hours old will not be available to export, so most useful for daily extracts:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/S3Export.html

For realtime delivery you would want to use the Subscriptions API:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/Subscriptions.html

Comment: A year later, but thanks! Hopefully this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by setting up a subscription to the Log Group that triggers a Lambda function. The function transforms the log data and writes it as a .log file to S3 or sends the records to Kinesis Firehose for collection, and then to S3 as an archive.

You can checkout the [full writeup](http://mlapida.com/thoughts/exporting-cloudwatch-logs-to-s3-lambda) or just the [Lambda Function](https://gist.github.com/mlapida/1166b18651a185e21a08#file-flowlogs-to-s3-lambda-py) if you're trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Loggly does not support similar service.

According to [Loggly Log File Monitoring Options](https://www.loggly.com/docs/file-monitoring/) you have those options:

1. Option

   - Setup new instance with cronjob to sync log from S3 to the local disk.
   - Setup rsyslog service and send this log file to Loggly.
2. Option

   - Using [Loggly File Upload](https://www.loggly.com/docs/file-upload/) how to and push log file with curl POST.

   curl -X POST -T FILE.TXT https://logs-01.loggly.com/bulk/TOKEN/tag/file_upload

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Some time since this question was asked, Loggly added support for Cloudwatch Logs.  It uses a Lambda function, probably similar to the solution by @Michael above.

https://www.loggly.com/docs/cloudwatch-logs/